# Java iText using Lithuanian letters

Tags: java, html, itext

I am trying to create PDF file with java and I need to use Lithuanian letters within file. I tried to use html code and use htmlWorker to parse it, however it does not work on most letters(it works on some). If anyone could help me with this I would gladly appreciate it.

```
    try {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pathy));
            document.open();
            HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);

            String s = ("<html>&#260;&#261;&#280;&#281;&#362;&#363;&#268;&#352;"
                    + "&#381;&#269;&#353;&#382;&#278;&#279;&#302;&#303;&#370;&#371;</html>");

            htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(s));
            document.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e2){

        }
```

I solved my issue by using unicode, not sure why it doesn't work with html code still...

```
Document document = new Document();

            try {
              PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pathy));
              document.open();

              BaseFont bfComic = BaseFont.createFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
              document.add(new Paragraph("ąĄčČęĘėĖįĮšŠųŲūŪžŽ", new Font(bfComic, 12)));
            } catch (Exception e2) {
              System.err.println(e2.getMessage());
            }
            document.close();
```

Comment: Define "it does not work on most letters". If you are having trouble with code that may throw exceptions, you should print the stack trace on catching an exception instead of ignoring it.

Comment: It works on letters "šŠžŽ", it does not work on letters "ąĄčČęĘėĖįĮųŲūŪ". I tried catching exceptions, but no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: What does "not work" mean in this case? Garbage is created? Nothing is created?

Comment: Nothing is created. Output should be all Lithuanian letters, but only "šŠžŽ" letters are created, where are no substitutes for other letters, no spaces, question marks, boxes, nothing at all.

Comment: *I solved my issue by using unicode* - more to the point, you solved it by not using HtmlWorker... That class has long since been deprecated in favor of XmlWorker due to numerous deficiencies.