# Lithuanian characters in pdf

Tags: itext, character

I am using itext to create pdf file in android app, but when pdf is created lithuanian characters are missing. Maybe somebody has any solution?

Comment: Most likely the font you use or the encoding you initialize it with don't contain those characters. As you don't show your voice in this regard, though, I can only guess.

Comment: data1  = "ąčęėįšųūž"

    

        document.open();

       

       
        Font f1 = FontFactory.getFont("resources/fonts/Timesroman.ttf", BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 7);
 

        Paragraph p11 = new Paragraph(data1, f1);
        p11.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

        document.add(p11);


            document.close();         After this codei in PDF i get only "šž"   I tried a lot of different fonts from samples, and they don't work.

Comment: You'll need to use the unicode encoding for the font.

Comment: Maybe somebody can write an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java iText using Lithuanian letters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28615324/2985643).